# Не работает выравнивание

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Помогите, в следующем коде не работает выравнивание. Выравнивает только высоту, то есть `60px`

```
document.getElementById('formpoik').style.margin = '60px 0px 0px 0px';
```

Подскажите что делать и как прописать `margin-left`

***JS***

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {  
        $('header').addClass("sticky"); 
        document.getElementById('menupo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("formpoik").style.marginLeft = "100px";
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
        document.getElementById('menupo').style.margin = '';
        document.getElementById("{formpoik}").style["marginLeft"] = "100px";
    }
});
```

***HTML***

```
<form id="formpoik" class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Введите здесь слово, которое нужно найти..." required>
    <button type="submit">Искать</button>
</form>
```

***CSS***

```css
#formpoik {
    margin: 60px 100px 0px 0px;
}
```

Пробовал

```
document.getElementById("{element id}").style.marginLeft = "20px";
document.getElementById("{element id}").style["marginLeft"] = "20px";
$("#{element id}").css("margin-left", "20px");
```

Не реагирует никак, но если в CSS меняешь, то всё нормально меняется, а в `scroll` вообще ни в какую.

Весь CSS код формы поиска

```
    /*форма поиска*/

 /*-------------------------------------*/

.cf:before, .cf:after{
  content:"";
  display:table;
}

.cf:after{
  clear:both;
}

.cf{
  zoom:1;
}

/*-------------------------------------*/   

.form-wrapper {
/*Размеры формы*/
width: auto;
max-width: 1500px;
min-width: 50px;
min-height: 0px;
height: 28px;
padding: 5px; /*Размеры рамки*/
background: #444;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /*закругление рамки*/
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
overflow-x: visible;
float: right;
}

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 680px; /*Ширина строки поиска*/
    height: 7px; /*Высота строки поиска*/
    padding: 10px 5px; /*Высота строки поиска*/ /*Ширина строки поиска*/
    float: left;    /*Выравнивание поискового поля относительно кнопкия*/
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma'; 
    border: 0; /*Отключение рамки поиска*/
    background: #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}    


.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 27px; /*Высота кнопки*/
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/30px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;    
}

.form-wrapper button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 6px; /*Курсор формы поиска*/
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before{
    border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}    

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #formpoik {
        margin: 60px 100px 0px 0px;
        }
```

Comment: [mcve] в виде сниппета?

Comment: интересный замес кода из jquery и plain javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginLeft = "50px";
```

Comment: Добавил код, проблема не решена

Comment: @TomasRedl вот [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0sprku8n/)

Comment: Ммм, у меня код не работает))

Comment: Скажите тогда по приоритетам, что выше ID или CLASS?

Comment: id, в фидле форма без левого марджина, при скроле добавляется 100px, если вернутся в начало страницы (scrollTop < 1) возвращается на место (убирается левый марджин), проверила еще раз, работает

Comment: Я CSS код добавил, не могу у себя найти ошибку, помогите пожалуйсто

Comment: @TomasRedl document.getElementById("{formpoik}").style["marginLeft"] = "100px";

Comment: @TomasRedl у вас обращение к элементу "{formpoik}", а не "formpoik",
так же значение марджина одинаковое

Comment: native:
document.getElementById("{element id}").style.marginLeft = "20px";
equal
document.getElementById("{element id}").style["marginLeft"] = "20px";

jQuery:
$("#{element id}").css("margin-left", "20px");

Comment: Можно так делать

Comment: Но в данном случаи не работает(((

Comment: Значение не важно, я как пример код отправил

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо, буду стараться

Answer (score 1):

Всем большое спасибо, нашёл решение проблемы
добавил position:absolute; в #formpoik